# Mac how to re-assign keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Mac OS X 10.6

In System Preference > Keyboard > Keyboard shortcuts, "Show Spotlight search field" and "Select the previous input source" keyboard shortcuts are conflict to each other. It seems can only be restored to default value. Can I customized re-assign them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-click on the assigned shortcut, and enter anything you want.

See Apple's Knowledge Base article, [Mac 101: Set your preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2490#l4) (in particular, its "Customize Your Keyboard Shortcuts" section) for details.